# I think my hibernation image in the encrypted swap partition is corrupted?

Tags: fedora, freeze, hibernate, dm-crypt

I have a hard drive with the below partition layout.
I can suspend-to-ram and resume as well as pass all the pm_test (without actually writing the image to disk). However, when I do the actual suspend-to-disk, upon resume, I got a short message saying PM is resume from dm-2 device, and just black screen.

Since my hard disk is encrypted, I figure perhaps my swap partition was corrupted on boot. Anyone has any suggestion?

lsblk

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                                          8:2    0     3G  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                                          8:3    0 220.4G  0 part  
  └─luks-6517ca17-aaad-423e-99f0-df9b0e4c9bc7 253:0    0 220.4G  0 crypt 
    ├─fedora-root                             253:1    0  53.4G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora-swap                             253:2    0    17G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─fedora-home                             253:3    0   150G  0 lvm   /home
```

/etc/crypttab

```
luks-6517ca17-aaad-423e-99f0-df9b0e4c9bc7 UUID=6517ca17-aaad-423e-99f0-df9b0e4c9bc7 none
```

/etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=fedora/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-6517ca17-aaad-423e-99f0-df9b0e4c9bc7 rd.lvm.lv=fedora/swap rhgb quiet resume=/dev/dm-2 hugepagesz=1G hugepages=2"
```

OS: Fedora Core 23 64-bit, 4.3.5-300.fc23.x86_64

P.S. I have tried to suspend to a non-encrypted swap partition (in a different hard drive, and non-lvm), so I know it's to do with my partition setup...